# Magento 1.9 - resave all products

Tags: magento, configurable-product, magento-1.9.1

I need to re-save all products in magento. I found solution (for 1.7 version):

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

// require magento core
require_once 'app/Mage.php';

// execute on admin store
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
foreach($products as $product) {
    echo $product->getName() . '<br/>';
    // save the product
    $product->save();
}

echo 'DONE';
?>
```

But this not working for magento 1.9.
I need to re-save all configurable products, if it possible.

Comment: Why do you need to "re-save" all configurable products? Some background information on your use case would help...

Comment: Because imported products did not show correnctly in frontend. But when I manually re-save product in admin panel - all data displays fine for saved item. But I have 8563 items. I found that it works even I make re-save only for configurable product - all childs saves to.

Comment: Have you tried reindexing all indexes?

Comment: Yes, but it not helps. I found solution about to re-save products and for manual save it works fine. But I have a lot of products so I need mass re-save solution...

Comment: Okay - how are you importing your products?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works, but you cannot see product name, try use sku field

Comment: no, it not. Because I didn't see any changes in frontend. Products still not appear.

Comment: Could you check your changes from admin? If you will see all changes that you need you should make reindex and clear page cache